# Spring batch, check jobExecution status after running the job directly?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have 2 jobs where i have to launch the job2 based on the the status of the job1.
is it right to make the following call:

```
        JobExecution jobExecution1 = jobLauncher.run(job1, jobParameters1);
        
        if(jobExecution1.getStatus()== BatchStatus.COMPLETED){
          JobExecution jobExecution2 = jobLauncher.run(job2, jobParameters2);
        }
```

i have a doubt that the initial `jobexecution1` status might not be final when the condition is checked.
if anyone could explain more about yhis process it would be great

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `TaskExecutor` implementation that you configure in your `JobLauncher`:

- If the task executor is synchronous, then the first job will be run until completion (either success or failure) before launching the second job. In this case, your code is correct.
- If the task executor is asynchronous, then the call `JobExecution jobExecution1 = jobLauncher.run(job1, jobParameters1);` will return immediately and the status of `jobExecution1` would be unknown at that point. This means it is incorrect to check the status of job1 right after launching it as a condition to launch job2 (job1 will be run in a separate thread and could still be running at that point).

By default, Spring Batch configures a synchronous task executor in the `JobLauncher`.

Answer (score 0):

```
There are multiple ways. We are using below option by chaining jobs by decider. Below is the code snippet . Please let me know if you face any issues.


public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        
        String exitCode = new Random().nextFloat() < .70f ? "CORRECT":"INCORRECT";
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(exitCode);
    }

}

@Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider myDecider() {
        return new MyDecider();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myTestJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("myTestJob")
                .start(step1())
                .next(step2())
                    .on("FAILED").to(step3())
                .from(step4())
                    .on("*").to(myDecider())
                        .on("PRESENT").to(myNextStepOrJob)
                            .next(myDecider()).on("CORRECT").to(myNextStepOrJob())
                            .from(myDecider()).on("INCORRECT").to(myNextStepOrJob())
                    .from(decider())
                        .on("NOT_PRESENT").to(myNextStepOrJob())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```